# Beautiful Soup .text and tag still attached

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So i'm using beautiful soup to get data from a table with 2 column.
Here's my code

```
print('Bulan-Tahun', end ='   ')
print('Inflasi')
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'table1'})
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    col = row.findAll("td")
    print(col[0].text)
    print(col[1].text)
```

and this is the result

```
Bulan-Tahun   Inflasi

                    Juli 2020
                

                    1.54 %
                

                    Juni 2020
                

                    1.96 %
```

The text result is located at the right because when i remove the .text, it's position is the exact position when the tag it still intact, but i want it to be only text without all the spacing. any solution? thank you

Comment: `print(col[0].text.strip())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to you use a .strip() method to remove the white space of the text.

Ex:

```
print(col[0].text.strip())
print(col[1].text.strip())
```

That should at least remove the white space around each col.

Answer (score 0):

You can minimally use [str.strip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) for your code.
For instance:

```
print(col[0].text.strip())
```

will output results without leading and trailing whitespaces.